# Error Building Giraffe (Chess Program): /opt/local/bin/as: assembler (/opt/local/bin/clang) not installed

Tags: g++

I'm trying to build the Giraffe Deep Belief Chess Playing program which I downloaded from Mercurial.

From README.md:
 Tested on Linux (GCC 4.9), OS X (GCC 4.9), Windows (MinGW-W64 GCC 5.1). GCC versions earlier than 4.8 are definitely NOT supported, due to broken regex implementation in libstdc++.

Here's the error:

```
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:giraffe davidlaxer$ make
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-function -std=gnu++11 -mtune=native -Wa,-q -ffast-math -pthread -fopenmp -DHGVERSION="\"efceca80bf74\"" -O3 -march=native -Wa,-q -I. -c backend.cpp -o obj/backend.o
/opt/local/bin/as: assembler (/opt/local/bin/clang) not installed
make: *** [obj/backend.o] Error 1
```

I'm on OS X 10.10.5.

```
port select --list clang
Available versions for clang:
    mp-clang-3.5
    mp-clang-3.7
    none (active)

David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:giraffe davidlaxer$ ls -l /opt/local/bin/as
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  admin  28012 Feb 15  2015 /opt/local/bin/as

David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:giraffe davidlaxer$ /opt/local/bin/as -v
Apple Inc version cctools-862, GNU assembler version 1.38

David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:giraffe davidlaxer$ file /opt/local/bin/as
/opt/local/bin/as: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:giraffe davidlaxer$ g++ --version
g++ (MacPorts gcc49 4.9.3_0) 4.9.3
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

From Makefile:

```
#CXX=g++-4.9  # I changed this - dbl
CXX=g++

# this is used to build gtb only
CC=gcc-4.9

HGVERSION:= $(shell hg parents --template '{node|short}')

CXXFLAGS_BASE = \
        -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-function -std=gnu++11 -mtune=native -Wa,-q -ffast-math \
        -pthread -fopenmp -DHGVERSION="\"${HGVERSION}\""
```

Comment: Try with `CXX=clang++`; it might work.

Comment: Yep.  CXX=clang++ and CC=clang.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve this issue using `Brew`,

```
$ clang
zsh: no such file or directory: clang


$ brew install llvm --with-clang --with-asan
==> Downloading http://llvm.org/releases/3.5.0/llvm-3.5.0.src.tar.xz
######################################################################## 100.0%
  /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.5.0: 1235 files, 171M, built in 16.8 minutes


$  clang -v
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```